# add checkbox to button

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a checkbox to a windows forms button. The purpose is to enable or disable a configuration regarding the checkbox state button.

Example Image:

[image]

Comment: If you post the direct link to the image, someone would be able to edit it into your question.. From a usability point of view though, this doesn't sound like a very good idea

Comment: Here it is : http://fr.tinypic.com/r/2ppx7yv/8

Comment: Its probably doable by creating your own `UserControl`. But again, it sounds like a bad idea from a usability point.. Users may find it hard/annoying when trying to click the checkbox, the mouse moves and it suddenly clicks the button (and vice versa). I don't understand what the checkbox is there for to suggest an alternative..

Comment: You _could_ create a custom Image Button. [MSDN: How to: Create a Custom Image Button Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172532%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: The application may have until 4 configurations. The goal is to identify immediatly and visually which configuration are active. Anyway I can also add a checkbox in the parameters panel. This seems to be a better solution to avoid a manipulation error.

Comment: @user3651845 - But you do that already in your image since your Config 2 is highlighted in blue. That is very clear to me that that config should be active

Comment: Not really, it shows the selected configuration. I tried to add another color when the configuration is active but it was too ugly

Comment: buddy @user3651845, there is no connection of reputation and adding image to question!

Comment: @Victor: Buddy, there is... It is a SPAM prevention rule.

Comment: I recommend you ask a separate question on [UX StackExchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) since they may be able to help you develop a more user friendly solution

Comment: Well, finally it will be just a checkbox in the params. It's not a crucial part of developement ;)
Thanks everybody !

Comment: hi you can try to achieve this with ToggleButton if it pressed then it is like checked and add an enum ToggleButtonState.On and ToggleButtonState.Off

Comment: You can do this by setting `checkbox1.Parent = button1;` also set its location etc..if you like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit from the existing button class and simply draw and interact with your CheckBox using the VisualStyles class.  I over-wrote the MouseDown method to prevent any clicking on the CheckBox area from firing the click event of the button:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

public class ButtonWithCheckBox : Button {
  public bool OptionChecked { get; set; }

  protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (GetCheckBoxRectangle().Contains(e.Location)) {
      this.OptionChecked = !this.OptionChecked;
      this.Invalidate();
    } else {
      base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics,
      GetCheckBoxRectangle().Location,
      this.OptionChecked ? CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal : CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
  }

  private Rectangle GetCheckBoxRectangle() {
    Rectangle result = Rectangle.Empty;
    using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics()) {
      Size sz = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(g, CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
      result = new Rectangle(new Point(this.ClientSize.Width - (sz.Width + 8), 8), sz);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow it's a nice answer you made here. I did this another way and I cannot test it now but I put it as accepted, I will certainly use it soon. Thanks LarsTech !

Answer (score 0):

- Use a `ToolStrip` control.

  - Add the buttons
  - On each button set the `CheckOnClick` property to `True`
  - Add your images (for the purposes of this demonstration I'll use form-scoped variables, but you could use an `ImageList` or read the images off the filesystem.. whatever)
  - Add a common click handler to swap out the images.

    ```
    '   Yes, this is VB, translate it if you need to.  
    Private config1Images As List(Of Image) ...

    Private Sub commonButtonClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConfigButton1.Click, ConfigButton2.Click, ConfigButton3.Click
        Dim button As ToolStripButton = sender
        Dim imageIndex As Int32 = 0

        If button.Checked Then
            imageIndex = 1
        End If

        If ConfigButton1 Is button Then
            button1.Image = config1Images(imageIndex)
        End If
        '   etc.
    End Sub
    ```

    This whole image swap is a little pointless because the ToolStripButton will change the background color for you when the button's `.Checked` property = `True`.